# Flutter Column - one Container should take the maximum available height

Tags: flutter

I have a `column` with 5 children. the third child should take the maximum available height. With `flex` property on the `expanded` widgets, on some screen sizes I get overflow warnings, without, child 2 and child 4 occupy more height than necessary.

how can I achieve that child 2 and 4 only take the maximum required height for for their content and child 3 uses the remaining height of the screen?

```
  Column(
children: [
SizedBox(
height: 60.0,
),
Expanded(
child: Container(),
),
Expanded(
child: Container(),
),
Expanded(
child: Container(),
),
SizedBox(
height: 60.0,
),),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 60.0,
        ),
        Container(
          // This widget will take as much space as the text takes, you can test it by adding some more text
          child: Text('Text or any other widget here'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          // Expanded will force its child to take all available space
          child: Container(),
        ),
        Container(
          // This widget will take as much space as the text takes, you can test it by adding some more text
          child: Text('Text or any other widget here'),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 60.0,
        ),
      ],
    )
```